# countr += 0 shows none pi2go

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, global

I have no idea anymore. I've been struggling for hours now.
I got a pi2golite here with wheel sensors. 
the wheelCount() isn't working anyway (or at least I dont know how)
so I've been trying to find another solution. 
The 2 motors I've got seem to run on different speed's. I wanted to see that in numbers to change the speed of each motor so they run the same.

```
import pi2go, time
pi2go.init()


running = True
countL = 0
countR = 0

def counter1():
   global countR
   countR += 0

speed = 60

try:
  pi2go.stepForward(50,10)
  time.sleep(2)
  print counter1()
  print countL

finally:
  pi2go.cleanup()
```

->
When I try to run it, the motor's run fine and turn off after the 10 steps (so it has to be counting)

it outputs this:
for countL -> 0
for counter1() ->None

Why none?

Comment: That is logical: `counter1` does not *return* anything, hence in that case it returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

This is **expected bahaviour**.

If you run code in a Python shell, then when you write an expression, the shell will print the *result* of the expression.

For a function call, this is what the function returns. In Python every function returns something. In case you do *not* specify a `return` statement, then `None` is returned. Some shells do *not* print `None`, but anyway, the result is `None` of sucht call.

So the function *updates* `countR`, then performs `return None` (implicitly). This is the result of the function call, and so the shell prints this. If you run code without the shell, then *nothing* is printed (as in no content at all).

You can let the function return the updated value. Furthermore you probably want to *increment* the value, so `+= 1`:

```
def counter1():
    global countR
    countR += 1
    return countR
```

Comment: Well now both values equal 0. Its supposed to count though. Why isn't it doing that? I don't seem why.

Comment: @Dati: well you increment it with `0`. `0` and `0` makes `0`. You probably want to increment, so `+= 1`.

Comment: thats what the librabry tell's me to write though:


# Global variables for wheel sensor counting

running = True

countL = 0

countR = 0

Or do I just set to 

CountL += 1

CountR +=1

instead?
I'm a total beginner. sorry 'bout that.

Comment: Do you actually understand what you write? If not I would really first try to decipher that, since this is rather basic, and things you will try to build on top of this, will only make it harder.

Comment: Change it to
    def counter1():
    global countR
    countR += 1
    return countR

outputs 1 now of course. but its not counting..

Comment: @Dati: it is: if you call it multiple times, each time it will return the next ite. This is basically what counting in programming does...

Comment: I think I found my problem now. Will update once I tried it.

Comment: Yup. I'm just dumb.
I misread the pi2go library.
I thought that "countR" and "countL" are already def'd as functions in the library. But they are just usual variable's.
No wonder they won't count a specific thing.
Thanks for your help though!
Thinking about your words made me think of that.

Better read thoroughly !